# How to set up layout to Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an Android 2.2 application.

Testing my layout with eclipse graphical layout I have a problem: it doesn't look good on Galaxy Nexus.

I have four image types: ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi. A layout and four dimens.xml files (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi).

If I modify dimens.xml to make it look well with `Galaxy Nexus` but it won't look well on other device, e.g. `Nexus One` (in eclipse graphical layout). So, I think I need something else.

Reading [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) I see there is another approach: instead of using normal, large, etc layout, I could use `sw<N>dp`. But this is beginning with Android 3.2, and I need to support Android 2.2.

**What do I need to add to make it look well on Galaxy Nexus?**

**Nexus One**:
[image]

**Galaxy nexus**:
[image]

Comment: What does "it doesn't look good" mean? Screenshots and relevant layout XML will be helpful here.

Comment: @Tanis.7x I've added two images.

Comment: This is a design problem. Redesign your layouts in order to stay together on different screen sizes.

Comment: I have edited my question with more details.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach I often happen to use it to think like web developers. Try to make your layout look good with layout stretched in whatever direction. Center the important part and make sure the image behind can be stretched in both directions. Then use an imageview for the background and set it to match_parent and scaletype to centerCrop. It doesn't work for everything but I'm pretty sure it would work for your sample.

In your case you could put everything you have right now inside another container (for example a RelativeLayout) then you center it and set the dimensions or make it wrap_content. The new top container should then match_parent and have the imageview I talked about as a child.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep the different densities for the images, for the layouts you want to use screen sizes e.g.

layout-large instead of layout-hdpi

**EDIT**

You want to have a folder layout like this:

- res/drawable-ldpi/[your image resources]
- res/drawable-mdpi/[your image resources]
- res/drawable-hdpi/[your image resources]
- res/drawable-xhdpi/[your image resources]
- res/layout/[your layout xml file]
- res/layout-large/[your layout xml file modified for big screens]
- res/layout-small/]your layout xml file modified for small screens]

See this link for further info:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

**EDIT2**

If you must stick to one layout then you need to edit the values in res/values-large/dimes.xml to affect large screen devices.

If you have and extra large device screen then you'd need to edit res/values-xlarge/dimens.xml and so on for each of the screen sizes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand you. Now I have one layout and four dimens.xml.

Comment: I'm doing the same, but instead of using layout, I only have one layout and four `dimens.xml`. And, this is not my problem, if I modify `/res/values-normal/dimens.xml` to fit with `Galaxy Nexus` it won't fit or looks well on `Nexus one`.

Comment: I think a better solution for you would be to design the layout completely in a layout xml file and not rely on loading values from another resource file. If I understand correctly what you're doing then it goes against design guidelines and will cause the problems you speak of.

Comment: In another question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626248/same-layout-looks-different-on-a-samsung-galaxy-tab, @Adinia, recommends me to make it with different dimens.xml.

Comment: Indeed, I think using dimensions is a good thing to do when you want the same layout, but I didn't meant that will solve everything, specially when you are working with images, as phones also have different screen ratio, beside different sizes and resolutions. Just as @Warpzit suggested here, I have also told you to try to redesign using a `RelativeLayout`, and maybe [9patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) images.

Comment: Yes, I'm using relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

[**one of my first questions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948903/how-to-handle-android-screens-fragmentations) was very similar to this one .

your problem in short is that you need to have your views placed and resized according to an image that you show on the background . sadly , android doesn't support it without some workarounds .

on silverlight&WPF there is a viewBox that does it automatically . flash has it because it's vector based . iphone has it because all of its screens have the same aspect ratio. but android doesn't have a solution for it yet.

i've even asked this same question in google developers day , and what the lecturer told me was that i should use openGL , even though my app was very simple.

for now , what you can do is :

1. the easy way : use multiple LinearLayout with weights . use views inside them with weights too in order to make rules about the positions and sizes. Lint will tell you that it is bad for performance , but if your views are not moving/resizing at all , it should be ok .
2. the advanced way: create your own layout , which will know exactly where to put views (and in which size) in relation to what you give to it. i've done it in the past , but i used imageViews instead of buttons (because i had to) .

there is also a bug with this approach (also found on solution #1) : on some screens their images didn't fit with the background image. if that's not your case , you can do it too.

3. the hardcore way : use openGl . it's will be easier to use third party libraries like andEngine or LibGdx .
4. the web-developers way : put it all in a website , show it, handle touches using an interface with android .
5. the no-buttons way: if you don't want to use the buttons , you can use simple math in order to know where the user has pressed , and not use any of the above solutions .

btw , if you stretch the image like what i see , it won't keep its aspect ratio . you need to handle it too . using openGl can help you with that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete answer. I will test your solutions and I tell you, but I don't know how to implement OpenGL solution.

Comment: about opengl , you can use the third party solutions i've mentioned . using andEngine doesn't even require you to learn openGL . it's quite a good solution . however , last time i've checked (about half a year ago) it had some weird bugs . i hope they are fixed by now. about LibGdx , it's more low level than andengine , but what i like about it is that it's cross platform - it can run within the desktop OS without any emulator (so it's also very fast to develop) .